# Getting error while accessing User Profiles Anonymously

Tags: 2013, development, user-profile, user-profile-service, anonymous-authentication

[image]I have to access the user profiles anonymously.

I have used-
`SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()`
to access the user profiles anonymously.

While accessing the user profiles getting the Error as:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: The user could not be authenticated to the Web site being accessed.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RunWithElevatedPrivileges` elevates the code block to the Web Application App Pool Account. You need to ensure that account has access to the User Profile Service. I should point out RWEP is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks! @Matthew :)
I'll post my Answer Step by step soon.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the **User of Application pool** of the current web Application(In the **IIS**).
2. Go to Central Admin => Manage service applications => User Profile Service Application => Administrators => Add => User of Application Pool which is mentioned in the **step 1** => Select Full Control and Save it.
3. You will see the users anonymously.

Please check image for the more details-

[image]